# How to send a String from one UITableView to another UITableView on different Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am sending a string from a UITableView to another UITableView. Both tables are on the different Views. The problem i am facing is that, I am sending title of cell from one table to show that string on to the label of CustomCell of second Table,but it crashes on reloadData method of second table. When I debug it gives the size of table 0*0;

Help me!

Comment: Check if you are releasing any variable. Also what kind of error is it ? signalabr or bad exc acc ???

Comment: Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.  Note: This is what i am getting on console.

Answer (score 0):

Try using appDelegate to send data between different views.

```
//to save vaule
myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.myText = @"Your saivng value comes here";

myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString myVal=appDelegate.myText;
```

Make sure you have a NSString in your appDelegate.

Comment: Sorry, Not got you! If you mean delegate method than i am using those.

Comment: if you are using the UIAppDelegate method then you should save the text in that and using that retrieve it.

Comment: Its simple just add a NSString myText; in you appDelegate. and use the code given above changing myAppDelegate to what ever is your file name.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following steps-

1. Send number of rows , and array of element for each row .
2. Assign number of rows in delegate in second view table.
3. Set array for element to current array of second view and get element from current array.